# SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration depreciated in Spring Boot 1.3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

When updating to Spring Boot 1.3 from 1.2.7 I found out that SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration is removed. I could not find any mention why and what is the replacement.

I used to extend it to inject some Rest validation. I can do that using RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter but I am not sure this is the correct way. Is it?

Comment: [Removed?](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [Commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/24c63c9b55956cc26e4c2517eba7a8426e2073ce) it seems that yes RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter is the correct update for SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration as it is not public any more .